# Not able to reset Kafka Offset

Tags: apache-kafka, offset

I am trying to reset the Kafka offset but not able to reset it.

current offset is 6 and trying to reset it to earliest and also tried to decrement by 1 
but it is not resetting and keep reflecting 6

```
kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server <server>:9092 --group EDWOFFSETGROUP_24 --describe
Consumer group 'EDWOFFSETGROUP_24' has no active members.

TOPIC                PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID     HOST            CLIENT-ID
EDW_TOTALS_JSON1 0          6               6               0               -               -               -
```

Approch#1

```
kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server <server>:9092  --group EDWOFFSETGROUP_24 --topic EDW_TOTALS_JSON1:0 --reset-offsets --shift-by -1
WARN: No action will be performed as the --execute option is missing.In a future major release, the default behavior of this command will be to prompt the user before executing the reset rather than doing a dry run. You should add the --dry-run option explicitly if you are scripting this command and want to keep the current default behavior without prompting.
[2019-12-04 14:43:14,364] WARN New offset (5) is lower than earliest offset for topic partition EDW_TOTALS_JSON1-0. Value will be set to 6 (kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$)

TOPIC                      PARTITION  NEW-OFFSET     
EDW_TOTALS_JSON1           0          6
```

Approch#2

```
kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server <server>:9092 --group EDWOFFSETGROUP_24 --topic EDW_TOTALS_JSON1 --reset-offsets --to-earliest --execute

TOPIC                      PARTITION  NEW-OFFSET     
EDW_TOTALS_JSON1           0          6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems data got purged by passing retention policy.
 If message got truncated it will get started from new position that will appeared on topic partition detail.

Please refer for [retention setting definition](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/topic-configs.html)

You can try with new consumer to validate

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper <zk_host>:2181 --topic test --from-beginning
```

If you are using new API then use below

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server <server>:9092 --topic EDW_TOTALS_JSON1 --from-beginnin
```

You can also check the offset details for partition using GetOffsetShell

```
   bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell
required argument [broker-list], [topic]
Option Description
------ -----------
--broker-list <hostname:port,..., REQUIRED: The list of hostname and hostname:port> port of the server to connect to.
--max-wait-ms <Integer: ms> The max amount of time each fetch request waits. (default: 1000)
--offsets <Integer: count> number of offsets returned (default: 1)
--partitions <partition ids> comma separated list of partition ids. If not specified, will find offsets for all partitions (default)
--time <Long: timestamp in milliseconds / -1(latest) / -2 (earliest) timestamp; offsets will come before this timestamp, as in getOffsetsBefore  >
--topic <topic> REQUIRED: The topic to get offsets from.
```

Example

```
kafka-run-class kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list localhost:9092 -topic vital_signs --time -1
```

Comment: I have checked retention time.

Comment: Thank you for your help! "retention", it was my case!